# How to sum the values of child objects in an array with DataWeave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

Below is the input. There is a parent child-relationship with objects. The `"Key"` key specifies that.
For e.g. `109-200C-001` is the child of `109-200C`. There will be n number of objects with different strings.

```
[
    {
        "Class": 1,
        "Amount": 2,
        "Key": "109-200C-001"
    },
    {
        "Class": 3,
        "Amount": 4,
        "Key": "109-200C"
    },
    {
        "Class": 8,
        "Amount": 7,
        "Key": "xyz-123-007"
    },
    {
        "Class": 8,
        "Amount": 4,
        "Key": "xyz-123"
    },
]
```

Need the output as below: Only the parent objects with the Amount of Child and Parent added.

```
[
    
    {
        "Class": 3,
        "Amount": 6,
        "Key": "109-200C"
    },
    {
        "Class": 8,
        "Amount": 11,
        "Key": "xyz-123"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first remove the child objects, then for each parent I sum the values of all elements that start with the same key. Encapsulating part of the logic in functions make the script very declarative in intent.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
fun isParent(a, x)=a some ( !($.Key == x.Key) and ($.Key startsWith x.Key))
fun sumChilds(a, x)=a filter  ($.Key startsWith x.Key) sumBy $.Amount
---
payload 
    filter isParent(payload, $)
    map {
        Class: $.Class,
        Ammount: sumChilds(payload, $),
        Key: $.Key
    }
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "Class": 3,
    "Ammount": 6,
    "Key": "109-200C"
  },
  {
    "Class": 8,
    "Ammount": 11,
    "Key": "xyz-123"
  }
]
```

I could have used the `update` operator instead of `map()`.

Find below generalized solution that works passing the keys as parameters:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays

fun isParent(a, x, key)=a some ( !($[key] == x[key]) and ($[key] startsWith x[key]))

fun sumChilds(a, x, key, valueKey)=a filter ($[key] startsWith x[key]) sumBy ($[valueKey] as Number)

fun totalizeChilds(a, key, valueKey)=
    a 
        filter isParent(a, $, key)
        map ((item, index) ->  item update {
                case v at ."$(valueKey)" -> sumChilds(payload, item, key, valueKey)
            }
        )
---
totalizeChilds(payload, "LOCAL_CODE", "AMOUNT")
```

For your second input you would need to map `AMOUNT` to string if you want an exact match.

Comment: It works for the original examples requested. You can adapt the method to the other input with minimal changes but I added a generic version that should work with any key names.